# Question about transition matrix Q in D3PM diffusion model for discrete state space

Tags: deep-learning, probability, stable-diffusion, discrete, generative

I have a question related to the following equations which are addressed in the section 3 of D3PM (Austin et al., 2021, NIPS, arXiv: 2107.03006v3: https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.03006.pdf).

It's about transition matrix Q that is used in discrete diffusion models.

My question is, when I rewrote the left hand side of eq. (3), I got the eq. (4). How can I convert eq.(4) to eq. (3)?

[image]